# passing command line argument to gawk script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a script `chk.awk` to which I want to pass some command line arguments. It has `awk` statements, `sed` command etc. Just for example I have taken a small program below to which I want to pass command line arguments.

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=$1
gawk '
BEGIN {
        printf "argc = %d\n argv0=%s\n argv1=%s\n var1=%s\n",ARGC,ARGV[0],ARGV[1],$var1
}'
```

But when I try :

```
$ sh chk.awk 10 20
argc = 1
argv0=gawk
argv1=
var1=
```

Above I tried to display the command line arguments by both ways i.e. `argv` & `$1`, but none of them work. Can anyone let me know where I am going wrong here? What is the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you give arguments to the shell script, but not to the awk script.
You must add `"$@"` to the call of `gawk`.

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=$1
gawk '
BEGIN {
    printf "argc = %d\n argv0=%s\n argv1=%s\n var1=%s\n",ARGC,ARGV[0],ARGV[1],$var1
}' "$@"
```

Otherwise you will your arguments in the shell-script and they will be not passed to `gawk`.

**Update 1**

If you have additional args (e.g. filenames that are to be processed),
you must remove the first portition of args first (in the `BEGIN` section):

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=$1
gawk '
BEGIN {
    printf "argc = %d\n argv0=%s\n argv1=%s\n var1=%s\n",ARGC,ARGV[0],ARGV[1],$var1;
    delete ARGV[1]
}' "$@" filename
```

Comment: @Chubin : Thanks a lot. this works, but there is another prob. i am using the input & output file in my prog like :                  #!/bin/bash
var1=$1
gawk '
BEGIN {
        printf "argc = %d\n argv0=%s\n argv1=%s\n var1=%s\n",ARGC,ARGV[0],ARGV[1],$var1
}{print $0}' "$@" in.file > out.file
when i run this script, i get the following error : $ sh chk.awk 10
gawk: cmd. line:2: fatal: cannot open file `10' for reading (No such file or directory)
can you plz update on how to pass the argument 10 here

Comment: @user1182722: You should remove the first argument in the BEGIN section, after you've processed it